# MediaRecorder.start() throw sometimes java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed

Tags: android, android-mediarecorder

i have Android app. which recording video via `MediaRecorder` and sometimes `MediaRecorder.start()` fails with this exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: start failed.
    at android.media.MediaRecorder._start(Native Method)
    at android.media.MediaRecorder.start(MediaRecorder.java:946)
    at com.example.example.RecordActivity.aeU(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.example.RecordActivity.p(Unknown Source)
    at com.example.example.RecordActivity$23.run(Unknown Source)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:158)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7225)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)
```

It's independently on device and Android version (from Android 5 to 8.1). Fails are very random. For example first 10 MediaRecorder starts is OK and 11. throw exception with the same setting, and i do not why. From total MediaRecorder starts will fail only a few times, for example only in 2%, but on some devices fail is more frequent. It's device bug, or Android bug on some devices? Can i reduce exception?  I have wait for example 100 ms after `MediaRecorder.prepare()` or something else? Any experiences with this problem?

Java code:

```
//c is Camera: Camera.open(cameraId)

MediaRecorder mr = new MediaRecorder();

//call methods in this order!
c.lock();
c.unlock();

//1st. Initial state:
mr.setCamera(c);

//2st. Initialized source:
if (recordAudio)
    mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.CAMCORDER);

mr.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);

//3st. config from profile:
CamcorderProfile profile = CamcorderProfile.get(Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK, CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_HIGH); //or other quality

mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

//Audio
if(recordAudio) {
    mr.setAudioEncoder(profile.audioCodec);   
    mr.setAudioEncodingBitRate(profile.audioBitRate);  
    mr.setAudioChannels(profile.audioChannels);
    mr.setAudioSamplingRate(profile.audioSampleRate);
}

//Video
mr.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec);
mr.setVideoSize(profile.videoFrameWidth, profile.videoFrameHeight);
mr.setVideoFrameRate(profile.videoFrameRate);
mr.setVideoEncodingBitRate(profile.videoBitRate);
mr.setOrientationHint(needRotation);
mr.setOutputFile(videoFile.toString());
mr.setPreviewDisplay(sur);

mMediaRecorder.prepare();
mMediaRecorder.start();
```

Comment: Please provide the java code..

Comment: Did you get a answer to this? I think it's related to `mr.setVideoEncoder(profile.videoCodec);`, currently you are assuming that the profile is available.